# Taylor series: Epsilon not differentiated?

Tags: differentiation, approximations

Why isn't epsilon differentiated with respect to time? (see my question on the right)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, given the fact that $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$ is written, that we are taking a Taylor series **in** $\epsilon$, which would involve differentiation with respect to $\epsilon$, rather than its arguments. Recall the expansion,

$$\frac{1}{(\epsilon+a)^3}= \frac{1}{a^3}-3\frac{\epsilon}{a^4} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$

where we think of the function as $f(\epsilon)$, rather than $f(t)$ or $f(a)$. Inserting the expansion yields,

$$2\ddot{\epsilon} +g -ga^3 \left(\frac{1}{a^3}-3\frac{\epsilon}{a^4} \right) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$
$$=2\ddot{\epsilon} +3g \frac{\epsilon}{a} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$

Comment: Damnit, you beat me to it haha. I need to get quicker at writing math ;)

Comment: So we differentiate in respect to epsilon rather than time, right?

Comment: @user42270 yes, that's the point

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor expansion in your question is carried out as follows:
$$\frac{ga^3}{(a+\epsilon)^3}=\frac{ga^3}{a^3\left(1+\frac{\epsilon}{a}\right)^3} $$

Now, we want to expand

$$f(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{\epsilon}{a}\right)^3} \hspace{2cm} \text{around}\ \epsilon=0$$

This Taylor expansion contains derivatives of $f(\epsilon)$, evaluated at $\epsilon=0$, but no derivatives of $\epsilon$ as this is the variable rather than the function.